# Reconnecting JMS listener to JBossMQ

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jbossmq

We have a Java listener that reads text messages off of a queue in JBossMQ. If we have to reboot JBoss, the listener will not reconnect and start reading messages again. We just get messages in the listener's log file every 2 minutes saying it can't connect. Is there something we're not setting in our code or in JBossMQ? I'm new to JMS so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Good question. This is something everyone runs into, so it's good to have the discussion recorded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should implement in your client code javax.jms.ExceptionListener.  You will need a method called onException.  When the client's connection is lost, you should get a JMSException, and this method will be called automatically.  The only thing you have to look out for is if you are intentionally disconnecting from JBossMQ-- that will also throw an exception.

Some code might look like this:

```
    public void onException (JMSException jsme)
    {
        if (!closeRequested)
        {
            this.disconnect();
            this.establishConnection(connectionProps, queueName, uname, pword, clientID, messageSelector);
        }        
        else
        {
            //Client requested close so do not try to reconnect
        }
    }
```

In your "establishConnection" code, you would then implement a `while(!initialized)` construct that contains a try/catch inside of it.  Until you are sure you have connected and subscribed properly, stay inside the while loop catching all JMS/Naming/etc. exceptions.

We've used this method for years with JBossMQ and it works great. We have never had a problem with our JMS clients not reconnecting after bouncing JBossMQ or losing our network connection.

Comment: Note that one should use Connection#setExceptionListener (with some JMS providers at least) to register the ExceptionListener.

Answer (score 9):

I'd highly recommend you use the [Spring abstractions for JMS such as the MessageListenerContainer](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html#jms-mdp) to deal with reconnection, transactions and pooling for you. You just need to supply a MessageListener and configure the MessageListenerContainer with the ConnectionFactory and the container does the rest.

Answer (score 6):

If you're purely a listener and do *no* other JMS calls other than connection setup, then the "onException() handler" answer is correct.

If you do any JMS calls in your code, just using onException() callback isn't sufficient.  Problems are relayed from the JMS provider to the app *either* via an exception on a JMS method call *or* through the onException() callback.  Not both.

So if you call any JMS methods from your code, you'll also want to invoke that reconnection logic if you get any exceptions on those calls.

Answer (score 1):

Piece of advice from personal experience.  **Upgrade to [JBoss Messaging](http://www.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/).**  I've seen it in production for 4 months without problems.  It has fully transparent failover - amongst many other features.

Also, if you do go with Spring, be [very](http://wiki.jboss.org/wiki/JBMSpringJMSTemplateNotes) [careful](http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html) with the [JmsTemplate](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html#jms-jmstemplate).